# Mongo DB how to find orphans in a tree?

Tags: mongodb, tree, mongodb-query

I have the `trees` collection with objects which have a tree like structure. I'm using [child references pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/) actually, but in my case the depth of each tree is undefined - it could be in range `[0:100]` approximately:

```json
{
  "_id": "tree1",
  "tag_id": "1",
  "children": [
    {
      "_id": "tree2",
      "tag_id": "2",
      "children": [
        {
          "_id": "tree3",
          "tag_id": "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "tree4",
      "tag_id": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

also I have the simple `tags` collection with objects like:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "one"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "two"
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "three"
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "name": "four"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5",
    "name": "five"
  }
]
```

As you can see, I have the orphan (**5**) which doesn't have a link inside `trees` collection:

```json
{
    "_id": "5",
    "name": "five"
}
```

I want to find all such orphans and remove them from `tags` collection.
I've tried to use `aggregate` method with `$lookup`:

```js
db.tags.aggregate(
 [
  {$lookup:
    {
        from: "trees",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "tag_id",
        as: "matched_docs"
    }
 }
 ]
);
```

But such approach joins and finds only "top" connections without looking to children array.
How can I solve the task using mongo queries? Maybe, it's better to use different data-structure, pattern or other aggregation method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Nested-Depth-for-BSON-Documents) of latest version

> ```
> Nested Depth for BSON Documents
>
> MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON   
> documents. Each object or array adds a level.
> ```

Mongodb is not fit for this schema. Hence, you cannot achieve this with huge dynamic levels of deeply nested arrays.

You can alter the schema or data store.

Comment: Agreed; take a look at `$graphLookup` and consider turning your deep tree into simple docs linked by parent-child ID.